# Is there any language pack Magento officially provides?

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, language

I am using **M2(EE)** and wondering if there's any **language pack** Magento officially provides.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Pls check here https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/magento-2-language-pack/

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question should be `NO`. But you can search several extensions on Magento marketplace, and the above shared the link as per @abdul in the comment for language packs.